# Different ways to distribute

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If I have $5$ bananas, $3$ oranges, and $8$ apples, how many ways can I distribute these
to $16$ friends, if each friend gets one fruit?

Would it simply be $5*3*8=120$?

Comment: Does it matter which friend gets which fruit?

Comment: It does not matter

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** There are $\binom{16}{5}$ ways to choose who gets the bananas. For every one of these choices, there are $\dots$.

Comment: So then there are $\binom{16}{3}$ and $\binom{16}{8}$ ways to choose the other 2 fruits

Comment: Not quite. There are $\binom{16}{5}$ ways to decide who gets the bananas. For each of these ways, there are $\binom{11}{3}$ ways to decide who gets the oranges, and now who gets the apples is determined. So the total is $\binom{16}{5}\binom{11}{3}$. Note that this simplifies in various ways, such as to $\frac{16!}{5!3!8!}$.

Answer (score 1):

As each one gets one fruit, you have to choose who gets the bananas, then you distribute the oranges among those who haven't got a banana, and the others get the apples. This gives:
$$
\binom{16}{8} \cdot \binom{8}{3}
  = \binom{16}{8, 3, 5}
$$
The last is a *multinomial coefficient*:
$$
\binom{n}{k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_r}
  = \frac{n!}{k_1! \, k_2! \, \ldots \, k_r!}
$$
where $k_1 + k_2 + \ldots + k_r = n$, the coefficient of $x_1^{k_1} \ldots x_r^{k_r}$ in $(x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_r)^n$.